# Set password hidden in FOS UserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-forms

I wanted to set the password field in registration form hidden since I don't need the password in my first step registration. The field is right now not showing since I have overridden the form, But still I could not submit the form because it says password should not be blank.

So I have tried this and its not working

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('plainPassword',HiddenType::class)
        ->add('sex')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('zip_code')
        ->add('age');
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ]);
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_bundle_registration_type';
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So however managed to solve this for now with the help of OlivierC!

So I used life cycle callbacks to persist the data in the entity.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html

Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
* @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = 'abcdef';
}}
```

Now it doesn't show as blank and for registration with password, I would need to update this field.

Comment: You should rename your method setPasswordValue and it must not have a parameter. Anyway, you're not using it

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder
    ->add('password', HiddenType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'validation_groups' => false
    ]);
```

You have a third parameter to provide options, you can use this to make it optional.

Comment: Alternatively, if you didn't need the password _at all_, you could override the User-Entity and remove the password field.

Comment: Ye, that as well.

Comment: @N.M. : No, I need the password for second step registration. So i cannot remove that. Any other idea?

Comment: NotBlank is the validation constraint, so that would need to be removed as well.  I'll see if I can find how to do that.

Comment: @Arcv ok give that a try.

Comment: @Flosculus Nope, doesn't help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145429/discussion-between-arcv-and-flosculus).

Comment: Considering it is at registration, you should instanciate a password value in your __construct method. This value will be overriden during your second step.
This way your user will be valid at the form validation.

Comment: That would render the user unable to login as he doesn't know his password, if logging in is required and actually possible between the two steps.

Comment: @N.M. what i understand from Arcv question is: in a first step the user fills the form with personal data and in a second step he defines a password. If so, this would be non-sense to ask for registration between those two steps

Comment: @OlivierC I've asked in chat and the user should not be able to login between the two steps. It would've been possible that the user is able to login using his, for example, username and DOB which would've made your solution not applicable, which is why I commented. Arcv has to manipulate the second registration to not actually _insert_ but _update_ a user, which is perfectly possible but still feels kind of hackish.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the NotBlank constraint you could override the FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml. Copy it to MyBundle/Resources/config/validation.xml and make changes you want.

Comment: I want the field to be hidden in only that form, the password is required in my case for some other form as well.

Comment: Why don't create another form ?